# NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code в WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-webforms

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in SOSSystem.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Сам код:

```
DataTable table = GridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
```

...

```
if (GridView1.HeaderRow != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        table.Columns.Add(GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text);
    }
}
```

В Error List 1 Warning:

> 'SOSSystem.Defualt.ID' hides inherited member 'System.Web.UI.Page.ID'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

**UPD**: Расширяю описание вопроса:

1. Ошибка вываливается на строчке

   ```
   table.Columns.Add(GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text);
   ```
2. Суть представленого кода - сортировка TemplateField в GridView.
3. Полный код страницы:

   ```
   namespace SOSSystem
   {
       public partial class search : System.Web.UI.Page
       {
               SqlConnection con = new  SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
           string _connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;


           protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
               if (!IsPostBack)
               {
                   BindData();
               }
           }


           protected void btnsearch_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {

               string find = "SELECT * FROM catalog WHERE(Name like '%' + @name + '%' or Autor like '%' + @autor + '%' or Editor like '%' + @editor + '%' or Year like '%' + @year + '%' or About like '%' + @about + '%' or Type like '%' + @type + '%')";
               SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(find, con);
               comm.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox7.Text;
               comm.Parameters.Add("@autor", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox7.Text;
               comm.Parameters.Add("@editor", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox7.Text;
               comm.Parameters.Add("@year", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox7.Text;
               comm.Parameters.Add("@about", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox7.Text;
               comm.Parameters.Add("@type", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox7.Text;

               con.Open();
               comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
               SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
               da.SelectCommand = comm;
               DataSet ds = new DataSet();
               da.Fill(ds, "picture");
               da.Fill(ds, "name");
               da.Fill(ds, "autor");
               da.Fill(ds, "editor");
               da.Fill(ds, "year");
               da.Fill(ds, "about");
               da.Fill(ds, "type");
               GridView1.DataSource = ds;
               GridView1.DataBind();
               con.Close();
           }

           protected void SortRecords(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)

                           {
                               string sortExpression = e.SortExpression;
                               string direction = string.Empty;

                               if (SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)

                               {

                                   SortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
                                   direction = " DESC";

                               }
                               else
                               {
                                   SortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
                                   direction = " ASC";

                               }

                               DataTable table = this.GetData();
                               table.DefaultView.Sort = sortExpression + direction;
                               GridView1.DataSource = table;
                               GridView1.DataBind();
                       }



                       private void BindData()
                       {

                           // specify the data source for the GridView

                           GridView1.DataSource = this.GetData();

                           // bind the data now

                           GridView1.DataBind();

                       }

                       public SortDirection SortDirection

                       {

                           get
                           {
                               if (ViewState["SortDirection"] == null)
                               {
                                   ViewState["SortDirection"] = SortDirection.Ascending;
                               }
                               return (SortDirection)ViewState["SortDirection"];
                           }
                           set
                           {
                               ViewState["SortDirection"] = value;
                           }
                       }



                       private DataTable GetData()
                       {

                           DataTable table = GridView1.DataSource as DataTable;

                           // add the columns to the datatable            
                           if (GridView1.HeaderRow != null)
                           {

                               for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
                               {
                                   table.Columns.Add(GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text);
                               }
                           }

                           //  add each of the data rows to the table
                           foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
                           {
                               DataRow dr;
                               dr = table.NewRow();

                               for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
                               {
                                   dr[i] = row.Cells[i].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", "");
                               }
                               table.Rows.Add(dr);
                           }

                           //  add the footer row to the table
                           if (GridView1.FooterRow != null)
                           {
                               DataRow dr;
                               dr = table.NewRow();

                               for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.FooterRow.Cells.Count; i++)
                               {
                                   dr[i] = GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[i].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", "");
                               }
                               table.Rows.Add(dr);
                           }

                           return table;

                           }

       }
   }
   ```

Comment: вероятно, отвечающие сами должны угадать, какая именно часть вашего кода вываливает исключение?

Comment: пожалуйста, переформулируйте ваше сообщение так, чтобы это был вопрос, а не bug-report. сделать это можно, нажав [edit].

Comment: @alexander barakin , достаточно ли той информации, что я добавил?

Comment: @DisguisePerceptron судя по всему ваш оператор as из первой строки возвращает null, то есть GridView1.DataSource имеет тип, отличающийся от DataTable. Посмотрите, что именно у вас там

Comment: @DisguisePerceptron запустите под отладчиком. он остановится в момент исключения - и вы сможете посмотреть, что именно null

Comment: @DreamChild посмотрел через точку останова - в table действительно null.

Comment: @DreamChild добавил полный код страницы. 
Логика работы такая: после запуска страницы есть поле ввода и кнопка. После на кнопке висит обработчик, который ищет в БД во всех полях нечто похожее на запрос и в случае успеха выводит это в GridView1. Дальше оно должно сортироватся, но увы нет. Как посоветуете это пофиксить? Спасибо

Comment: @DisguisePerceptron ну вы в GridView1.DataSource лучше посмотрите - проблема там. table у вас принимает значение null потому что GridView1.DataSource не является DataTable, но судя по всему является чем-то другим.

Comment: @DreamChild ага, он тоже является null. И  когда выше по коду смотрю - там тоже null. И я аж как-то растерялся в поиске причино-следственных связей.

Comment: @DisguisePerceptron падает при попытке сортировки? или при каком-то другом действии?

Comment: @PashaPash да, запуск-поиск-отрисовка GridView1 происходит корректно.

Comment: @DisguisePerceptron ок, сейчас распишу ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что в ASP.NET страница и контролы на ней не существуют постоянно. Они создаются на время обработки запроса, к концу обработки сохраняют свое состояние во ViewState, рендерятся в html, после чего сами экземпляры контролов выбрасываются.

При нажатии на клиентской стороне чего-то, что вызывает постбек - например, кнопки  в контроле сортировки, происходит следующее:

- запрос приходит на сервер
- создается новый экземпляр страницы со всеми контролами
- его состояние загружается из ViewState
- у страницы вызывается обработчик соответствующего click/change события - `SortRecords`

Проблема только в том, что это уже не тот же экземпляр страницы. И не тот экземпляр грида, у которого вы выставили DataSource. Это совершенно другой объект, просто часть его свойств загрузилась из ViewState.

Стандартные контролы не сохраняют во ViewState свой датасорс - они сохраняют только результат датабанйдинга. Например, грид сохраняет количество строк, и данные для каждой ячейки каждой строки. Но он сохраняет только реальный результат - в виде текста конкретных `Label`-ов.

Сам DataSource postback не переживает (и не должен). Вам стоит добавить проверку на `table == null` и подставлять `new DataTable()`:

```
DataTable table = (GridView1.DataSource as DataTable) ?? new DataTable();
```

А еще лучше - заново выбирать данные из базы, с указанием сортировки - именно на такой сценарий рассчитан механизим байндинга, и именно поэтому он не сохраняет датасорс.

Иначе вы получите проблемы, например, при попытке включить постраничное отображение - данные для 2-й страницы просто не будут сохранены во ViewState.

Comment: Спасибо за такой развернутый ответ.


Каким образом передать в SELECT-запросе  значение столбца, по которому мы сортируем выдачу?

Comment: @DisguisePerceptron дописать в SQL `+ " ORDER BY " +  sortExpression + direction`

Comment: Переписал кучу кода, как результат sortExpression + direction - doesn't not exist in the current context. Сомневаюсь, что самостоятельно допишу это до конца. Может  можете посоветовать альтернативный способ сортировки для TemplateFileds?

Comment: @DisguisePerceptron могу посоветовать вынести весь код из `btnsearch_Click1` в метод `BindGrid(sortExpression, direction)` и вызывать его из всех мест, где данные грида обновить (показать, отсортировать). но код я за вас не напишу :(

Comment: попробовал реализовать указанным способом, но у меня ничего не вышло - я запутался в коде. Думаю, что перепишу код всей страницы.
Но я очень благодарен за такой раскрытый интересный ответ - он мне полезен.